# Detecting Edge browser version (using Javascript or C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, browser, microsoft-edge, user-agent

Edge user agent looks something like this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063
```

(Notice Edge/15.15063 at the end)

Now when I look up actual browser version in Edge, I see this info about app:

```
Microsoft Edge 40.15063.674.0

Microsoft EdgeHTML 15.15063
```

So you see, user agent actually responds with EdgeHTML version.

**My question is, how do I get Edge version? (not EdgeHTML version)**

**C#** is even worse: His Request.Browser static class responds with
Browser: "Chrome", Version: "52.0", so this is out of the question.

Comment: User agent string is notoriously difficult to make sense of. First off, it can be spoofed. But also the contents may vary depending on what other browsers are installed on the system. The order may not always be the same. Other browsers may include the data you're looking for but not actually be Edge (they could be, for ex, Firefox yet reporting that edge is installed)

Comment: Edge UA string ends in `Edge/<version>` is that not good enough?

Comment: What is relevant to the webpage is the engine version (EdgeHTML 15.15063), since it determines the available features. The browser version is less relevant for that. In general, I would recommend to not use the browser version to check for available features, but a tool like modernizr that checks for specific features.

Comment: Use feature detection.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is if you want to get the software version number programatically either on the server or the client, you can't. The browser does not expose that.

I'm not convinced that this is something you should do for any reason because of the dozens of alternative ways to do just about anything anyone would want to do when detecting browser version.

However, if you really want to get the actual version then there is a table in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge#Development) which contains what appears to be a one to one correspondence between the EdgeHTML layout engine version and the Edge version. There does not seem to be a case where he same Edge version had multiple EdgeHTML versions. You will have to maintain the list manually.

For example:

15.15063 maps to 40.15063 relased for Desktop on April 11, 2017